# Site not loading after install ssl

Tags: magento-1.9, ssl

I enable ssl certificate, then my site not loading.
I enable `secure url` from admin before ssl enabled. and also change `core_config_data` `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` to https://

What is the issue?here attach screenshot [image]

Comment: did you cleared cache ?

Comment: Did you check the .htaccess?

Comment: what is the need to check .htacess